# How to properly store Process ID (PID) on Windows

Tags: windows, process, pid

I'm trying to write a simple background process for myself which will run, obviously, in the background. It should be cross-platform, so it will run both in Windows and Linux.

I will interact it via command line. I've never done it before but I think one of the the proper ways to do it is to write a script which will spawn another process that will work as a daemon. Then later on this script will get a handle to that particular process which runs and do whatever with it. This isn't the actual question, but if there is anything wrong with that approach, I'm all ears.

Anyway, back to the actual question. In order to get a reference to that process, I need its ID. So I need to store the pid somewhere so I can read it later.

For Linux systems, I've read that the cannonical way to store the process ID is to save it in a `.pid` file under `/run`.

So, how should one implement this in Windows platforms? What is the cannonical way to do it? Or Windows takes a whole different approach to this?

Comment: There is no canonical way on Windows. You are welcome up make up any mechanism you like.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. Is there a "best practice" though? Or shall I just create a dot folder in the user directory and put it in there?

Comment: You probably want it in a place that cleans up automatically when the first process exits. Otherwise, if the user logs off and back on (say), the second logon will see the leftover files in the user directory and think there is a copy still running. A named shared memory block is one way. But really, once you get the PID, you'll presumably want to communicate with that first process, so you may as well just use the IPC channel itself as the way to detect the first process.

Comment: Perfect, I'll give it a shot. Thanks.